# What to use with "all"?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Sentence 1.

> All **works** of creative writing have aesthetic appeal.

Sentence 2.

> All **work** of creative writing have aesthetic appeal.

Which one is/are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rishav

It has nothing to do with **all**, rather with **works** - a plural noun.

If you want to use **work** (mass noun) then use **has** an ..

Comment: Please explain in more lucid manner.

Comment: @Rishavagarwal "Works" is plural, and thus agrees with the plural-form verb "have".  "Work" is either singular or mass, and in either case should take a singular verb-form, specifically "has", resulting in "all work of creative writing has aesthetic appeal".  "Have" can be singular, but not in the third person with indicative mood, which is what your sentence has.